# Websites to Have Sentences/Passages Recorded in Russian by Native Speakers

Tags: произношение

Is there any website that exists where I can have sentences or passages in Russian recorded for me? I like practicing my spoken Russian with translated sentences in spaced repetition programs such as Anki or Memrise, but I want to add audio to these sentences that I've selected to study (from Tatoeba.com, Anki decks and other sources). I am aware of forvo.com, though it is for words, and rhinospike.com, but are there any other resources available for getting recordings in Russian? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the mention of Native Speakers. 
And nobody could give You an answer.

So I tried some tests at [translate.yandex.ru](https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F.&lang=ru-en) .
Speech engine wouldn't admit any critical error during the tests:

> `сегодня` по-русски читается как `севодня`; `часы` по-русски читаются
>   как `чисы`,  в слове `дядя` слышится легкое `з` — `дзядя`.

*For rapid control* I dare to say that it's suitable.

A [more finer-grained analysis](https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%2C%20%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%2C%20%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%2C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F.&lang=ru-en) is also possible. 
The consonant sounds of Russian fall into two classes: hard and soft. Russian spelling, unlike English, is almost phonetic, spelling by a small number of definite rules. Certain Russian words show a consonant variation.

```
should be
pronounced
 |
 |                An engine failure designated by X
hard __________________________________________________
 .               |                          |          |
 .               X                          X          |
 .               |                          |          |
 .           филателист    фен    шинель    демарш     тест     агрессия.
 .                         |        |                             |
 .                         |        X                             |
soft ______________________|________|_____________________________|
```

The test is failed, but it's utterly negligible.

Comment: Being the native speaker, I really doubt if I could pass such a test myself ;-) BTW. The word "шинель" allows both hard and soft variants.

Comment: филателист with soft т? No way!

Comment: @Anixx , In `филателист, демарш, тест` the sound `t` must be a hard consonant, as indicated above.

Comment: @Avtokod in your diagram it shows that in филателист the т should be soft.

Comment: @user4419802 http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0641.htm `шинЭль` is wrong

Comment: @Anixx , it's my fault that my diagram have an ambiguity. I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [OpenLanguage RusPod](http://openlanguage.com/library/learn-russian/13/complimentary-russian-course/28) is a good one..